# Почему может тормозить БД PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Ситуация такая. Есть БД PostgreSQL в которую пишутся результаты парсинга данных.
В начале все работало достаточно быстро и в час писалось порядка 4000 тыс записей.
По мере роста БД до 20GB (3 млн записей) скорость вставки записей упала до 1000 в час.

Чисто теоретически могут прилетать дубликаты данных (точнее свежие версии). Поэтому нужны индексы.
Впрочем пробовал и без них. Если их вообще удалить, то скорость не особо возрастает (прирост не более 10%).

На колонке по которой проверяю дубликаты - MyID стоит HASH index.

Пробовал подкручивать настройки PostreSQL:

```
synchronous_commit = off
```

и

```
shared_buffers = 1024MB
```

Смена SSD на NVRAM тоже не дает какого-то успер ускорения т.е. очевидно, что проблема не в этом.

Я бы понял если бы индексы как-то все тормозили, но нет. Их удаление\добавление погоды не делает особой.

Данные прилетают ко мне в виде готовых SQL т.е. у меня нет возможности использовать prepered statment если это конечно погоду какую-то делает т.к. парсер выплевывает INSERT'ы как текст.

Вместо hash index пробовал b-tree, но мне показалось что hash index чуть быстрее работает т.к. у меня по колонке MyID поиск только в режиме `=` идет. Поиск пока главным образом на случай если прилетит дубликат (тогда я ловлю исключение и выполняю операцию удаления старых данных).

Во время вставки PostgreSQL почему-то крайне сильно нагружает CPU
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1000 в час ... вы хотите сказать, что один insert работает 3.7 секунды ? "_тогда я ловлю исключение и выполняю операцию удаления старых данных_" - А зачем так сложно, добавьте в insert `on conflict do update`, это можно сделать просто дописывая его в конец запроса, не модифицируя основную часть

Comment: Дубликаты крайне редки -- несколько в день. Поэтому реализовал через исключения.

"1000 в час ... вы хотите сказать, что один insert работает 3.7 секунды ?" получается что так. И я не могу понять причину.

Comment: Ну вы руками insert выполните и посмотрите сколько он идет. может дело все таки не в нем, а в том алгоритме, который его выполняет.

Comment: Если руками в SQL менеджере выполнить он выполняется практически моментально. Но с другой стороны микросервис который выполняет вставку просто ловит INSERT и дальше просто выполняет его в транзакции. Я ума не могу приложить как он может тормоза вызывать.

Вот код обработчика https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/a7311a5ff15e64c6be649b8bc7f680ab

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто вам присылают массив insert и массив delete и вы в случае, если произошел хотя бы один дубль, пытаетесь выполнить все delete из пакета. И если пакет большой, а дубль где нибудь под конец массива, то получаем много вставок, потом откат всего, попытку удалить все лишнее и опять вставку всего пакета.

Comment: @Mike да именно так и есть, но эти ситуации единичные. Такое возможно несколько раз в сутки. Я не могу понять что именно может тормоза вызывать. Не микросервис же?

Почему-то CPU usage dj время операции вставки у Постгрес 80-99%. 

Парсер который генерит SQL INSERT сам по себе (без взаимодействия через микросервис с БД) работает крайне быстро.

Comment: установите `log_min_duration_statement` скажем 200ms и посмотрите в логе, действительно ли проблема именно с временем выполнения запроса. Если так, то insert-ы там будут показаны с временем выполнения на стороне БД.

Comment: foreign keys есть на таблицах? Индексы для них? Триггеры?

Comment: @RomanKonoval реально спасибо! Помогло!!! Нашел причину!!!

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov напишите ответ, как именно искали и что нашли. Другим пригодится, да и интересно же, в чем причина.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я не думаю что ответ кому-то поможет т.к. проблема вылезла вообще в другом месте. Не в таблицах куда я результаты записываю, а в таблицах где я у самих данных флаг обработки меняю. Т.е. это уже вопрос архитектуры решения. Но совет с `log_min_duration_statement` реально показал мне узкое место.